# how to get documents with user information (firestore)

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have collection with documents.
Structure (fields):

```
questions
- question
- userID
```

and my project uses Firebase Authentication. How to get questions with data about author of each question (avatar and name) in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store every user in collection (ex. 'users' ) after register, and then make leftJoin with both questions and users collections.

something like this:

```
async function getQuestionsWithAuthors() {
        const result = [];
        const questionsSnap = await firebase.firestore().collection('questions').get();
    
        for(const doc of questionsSnap.docs) {
            const questionData = doc.data();
    
            const userData = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(questionData.userID).get();
            result.push({...questionData, user: userData});
        }
    
        return result
    }
```